# deleting and sorting elements of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have made this simple code to delete and sort elements of a vector. I have checked it many times, both sorting and deletion algorithm is correct when I run them individually, but there is a problem, when I delete an element then sort the vector in descending order the program puts a garbage a value at '0' index, but works fine if I do sorting in ascending order.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Here is the image of a sample run of the program [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KS4g.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool flag = 1;
    int size = 5,delind;

    vector <int> v1;
    v1.resize(size);

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nenter a no. ";
        cin>>v1[i];
    }

    // index of the element to be deleted
    cout << "\nEnter the index of no. to delete: ";
    cin >> delind;

    for(int i = delind; i < size; i++)
    {
        v1[i] = v1[i+1];
    }
    --size;
    v1.erase(v1.begin()+size);

    for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << v1[i];
    }
    cout << "\n sorting";
    // sorting

    while (flag == 1)
    {
        flag = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(v1[i] < v1[i+1]) // works fine with if(v1[i]>v1[i+1]) 
            {
                flag = 1;
                swap(v1[i],v1[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << v1[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may simply do `v1.erase(v.begin() + delind); std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`

Comment: Please edit your post with details from your debugging session, such as which statement is giving you issues and the values of the variables used by the statement.  Also state expected and actual values / behavior.

Comment: @Jarod42 I suspect this is an exercise to learn how to traverse vectors. Using library functions doesn't achieve this. It's hard to come up with toy problems that are appropriate for pedagogy that aren't already implemented in libraries.

Comment: Your basic text output does not need an image. Just copy it into your post.

Answer (score 1):

You have an off by one error with your sorting portion. In the following lines:

```
for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
{
  if(v1[i]<v1[i+1]) // works fine with if(v1[i]>v1[i+1]) 
  {
    flag = 1;
    swap(v1[i],v1[i+1]);
  }
}
```

At this point `size` is 4, and `v1.size()` is also 4. In the for-loop `i` goes from 0 to 3 like usual. But you are using `v1[i+1]`, so your loop will try to access `v1[4]`, which is out of bounds and gives you the garbage value that you are seeing.

To fix it, just fix your loop bounds:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
```

Comment: Or simply use `std::sort`.

Comment: but I have already decremented size by 1 when i delete an element so it's value is already 3 when it comes to this step Omada

Comment: @Waleed `size` starts at 5, and then you decrement it by one, so it should be 4. Try printing out what `size` is maybe?